# Spring WebFlux Filepart DataBuffer cant read more than 108 lines

Tags: java, spring, webflux

After downloading the file through the controller, an error occurs in the service.
There are 122 lines in the file, but it only reads 108.
Has anyone encountered such a problem?

[Debug vars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vNKz.png)

[109 line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHZMN.png)

[Fileparser code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4pj7.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this method, the filePartFlux is directly passed from the controller layer. Then we flat map filePartFlux and get a new Flux stream.
It may help you by using this code you can upload any file and get a string

```
filePartFlux.flatMap(filePart ->
    filePart.content().map(dataBuffer -> {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
        dataBuffer.read(bytes);
        DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
        return new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }))
```